# Why does Windows not launch specific application associated with a file type?

Tags: windows, java

I have .jsp files associated with 'javaws' (Java Web Start) from my JRE installation.  When I double click on .jsp files nothing happens.  If I associate the .jsp files with other applications such as 'notepad', I see the file opening.  This problem is only with 'javaws'.  *It is also specific to one laptop.*  We have a number of users that use the application that is associated with .jsp file and we see no problems, except for this one laptop.

The application launches fine from the command line.

```
c:>javaws test.jsp
```

But double clicking on test.jsp does not launch the application.

I have installed/re-installed different versions of Java as well without success.  On other laptops this works fine with any versions of java that has 'javaws' (Java 8 and earlier).

What could be the issue?